# Group rows where time difference is not bigger than 15 min

Tags: mysql, time, group-by, between

I'd like to group rows that are not bigger than 15 min in between. I like to see when a user have been logged in and have a "session".

Table

```
Time
2016-11-15 11:37:34
2016-11-15 11:35:04
2016-11-15 11:21:11
2016-11-15 09:37:22
2016-11-15 09:27:01
2016-11-14 21:37:59
2016-11-14 21:33:35
2016-11-14 21:31:14
```

Result:

```
Start                 End
2016-11-15 11:21:11   2016-11-15 11:37:34
2016-11-15 09:27:01   2016-11-15 09:37:22
2016-11-14 21:31:14   2016-11-14 21:37:59
```

This is my current query:

```
SELECT 
ROUND(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(Time)/900) as Session
FROM workouts
GROUP BY Session
ORDER BY Session DESC
```

But it only groups all rows that are in between 15 min.

Comment: I do not what an 15 min interval. What I like is if the difference between last row and current row is not bigger then 15 min. I did update the question

Comment: Are all the ids the same? If so, why bother with that column at all?

Comment: @Strawberry I have removed the id column. Do you have any idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not after a GROUP BY at all...

```
SELECT x.* 
  FROM my_table x 
  LEFT 
  JOIN my_table y ON y.dt > x.dt 
   AND y.dt <= x.dt + INTERVAL 15 MINUTE 
 WHERE y.dt IS NULL;
```

Edit:

To answer the amended question, you might consider something along these lines. It looks considerably more complicated, but in actual fact, it probably executes quicker...

```
SELECT MIN(dt) start
     , MAX(dt) end 
  FROM 
     ( SELECT dt
            , CASE WHEN @prev > dt - INTERVAL 15 MINUTE THEN @i:=@i ELSE @i:=@i+1 END rank
            , @prev:=dt 
         FROM my_table
            , ( SELECT @i:=0,@prev:=null ) vars 
        ORDER 
            BY dt
     ) a 
 GROUP 
    BY rank;
```

To see how it works, it may help to run the subquery (a) on its own

Comment: Sweet! Is there a way to get the first time of the session as well?

Comment: I guess with a UNION or another JOIN - but I suggest you edit your question to make it clearer what you're after.

Comment: ...to something considerably harder :-)

Comment: sorry mate :)  any idea how to get this?

Comment: is it possible to ask a little more about this? or maybe I should create an new question at stack, so more people can get the same help?

Comment: Unless it's a minor development, I think a fresh question, referencing this one, is the best way to go.